# Using siunitx S columns with keyval macro-expanded entries

Tags: tabularx, siunitx, key-value

I have the following table that compiles with regular 'c' columns, but doesn't work with an S-column.  Is there a way to format the following table using 
alignment features in the siunitx package?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\define@key{results}{a}{\gdef\a{#1}}
\define@key{results}{b}{\gdef\b{#1}}
\define@key{results}{c}{\gdef\c{#1}}

\newcommand{\row}[1]{\setkeys{results}{#1}\a & \b & \c}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}%     % doesn't work as an S column
\row{a=1.112,b=4.5,c=5.6}\\
\row{a=3.2,b=6.134,c=-5.6}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I've looked into the [siunitx](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) documentation (specifically Section 7.2 ("Expanding content in tables"), but haven't been very successful in implementing 
any of their suggestions.

It seems like I should want the `\row{...}` command to be expanded *before* being aligned with the S column, but I am not even sure if that is the right question to be asking

As an aside, I would like to use keyval arguments mainly because I would like to be able to pass more than 9 arguments to a "row" command.  I won't likely use all input values, but want flexibility in which ones I choose to use and how I use them.   Also, I like the idea of formatting data using named macros `\a & \b & \c` rather than  `#1 & #2 & #3`, as it seems that this reduces the chances of making errors when creating table entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use `xkeyval` for this, but `expl3`.

The main problem is with the first column: if you want to set the keys, the first column cannot be `S`; a trick is to use a “phantom” column.

I added a `\rowformat` command to set the order of the keys. In the image, the second table is the same as the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\rowformat}{m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__donna_table_rowformat_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__donna_table_rowformat_seq
     { \prop_item:Nn \l__donna_table_row_prop { ##1 } }
   }
  \cs_set_protected:Nx \__donna_row:
   {
    \exp_not:n { \tl_set:Nx \l__donna_table_row_tl }
     { & \seq_use:Nn \l__donna_table_rowformat_seq { & } }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\row}{m}
 {
  \prop_clear:N \l__donna_table_row_prop
  \keys_set:nn { donna/table } { #1 }
  \__donna_row:
  \tl_use:N \l__donna_table_row_tl
 }
\prop_new:N \l__donna_table_row_prop
\seq_new:N \l__donna_table_rowformat_seq
\tl_new:N \g__donna_table_row_tl

\keys_define:nn { donna/table }
 {
  unknown .code:n = \prop_put:NVn \l__donna_table_row_prop \l_keys_key_tl { #1 },
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\rowformat{a,b,c}

\begin{tabular}{
  c@{} % the phantom column
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.1]
}
\row{a=1.112,b=4.5,c=5.6}\\
\row{a=3.2,b=6.134,c=-5.6}\\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.1]
}
1.112 & 4.5 & 5.6 \\
3.2 & 6.134 & -5.6\\
\end{tabular}

\rowformat{a,c,b}
\begin{tabular}{
  c@{}
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.1]
  S[table-format=1.3]
}
\row{a=1.112,b=4.5,c=5.6}\\
\row{a=3.2,b=6.134,c=-5.6}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip on adding the phantom column, i.e. the following fix seems to work `\tabular{c@{}SSS}}` seems to be the only change that I needed to get my code to compile.

Comment: But I'll be honest - I am unfamiliar with the `Expl` syntax - is this a programming language in Latex?  Why do you prefer it over what I did?

Comment: I just noticed that the phantom column trick seems to prevent the first column from formatting correctly.  That is, the numbers are not aligned on the decimal.

Comment: Edit to first comment : I also need to add an `&` after the `setkeys` command in my `\row` macro.

Comment: @Donna Yes, I added one `&` too. The advantage of my approach is that you can define the keys on the fly in the `\rowformat` command.

Comment: Thanks again for the very useful answer.  I upvoted it because the phantom column trick was so simple, and I always wondered with that `@{}` was doing.   I still am not committed to the longer "latex programming", though, in part, because using the keyval, I can easily rearrange the columns.  I realize I have to come up with a a new macro for each type of row, but this isn't a problem.  But more importantly, I plan to include some simple calculations as part of a column result (i.e. column 3 might be column 2/column 1),  and it isn't clear how to include that in your longer code.

Comment: @Donna That requires a new question with the details and using `expl3` is surely better for it, as it already provides floating point computations.